# Service Does Not Execute Repeatedly As Expected

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

I've created a service which I expect to repeat every 15 seconds - but it does not repeat - ever. I'm not sure exactly what I've overlooked or messed up but I could really use a hand pinpointing the issue.

P.S.

I'm noticing everything seems to work until it is supposed to reach private void startServiceTimer() {

Thanks in advance!

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;

    public static final String swappedMdn(Context ctx) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        // Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
        String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();

        // Insure MDN is 10 characters
        if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null)
            mdn = "0000000000";

        // Extract last 10 digits of MDN
        if (mdn.length() > 10)
            mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length());
        char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
        char digit;
        for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length()) % 2; index += 2) {
            digit = data[index];
            data[index] = data[index + 1];
            data[index + 1] = digit;

            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DataCountService.class);

            SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
                    Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
            Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("0", new String(data));
            editor.commit();

        }

        return String.valueOf(data);

    }

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (intent == null) {

            // Exit gracefully if service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {

            if (extras != null) {

                String newMdn = swappedMdn(this);

                text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;1")) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

                    // get the date
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "hh/mm/ss/MM/dd/yy");
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    String tag = ";";

                    // String mdn =
                    // extras.getString(DataCountUtilities.swappedMdn(this));
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String DToDevice = s.format(new Date());
                    String status = (settings.getString("status", "0"));
                    String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag + status
                            + tag + settings.getString("0", newMdn) + tag
                            + DToDevice + tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr + settings.getString("last_month", "0"));
                    info = "USI" + info.replace("USI", "");

                    // info = (info.replace("CN", "CO")).replace("WN", "WO");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(info);
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO");
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO");
                    info = b.toString();

                    // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                                null);

                        // set status to enabled
                        Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("status", "1");
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();

                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null, info, null,
                                null);
                    }
                }

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
            } else if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                    "//USR;0")) {

                // set status to disabled
                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("status", "0");
                editor.commit();
                //stopSelf();

            //  return flags;


                if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {

                    period = Constants.PERIOD;
                    delay_interval = Constants.DELAY_INTERVAL;

                } else {

                    period = Constants.DEBUG_PERIOD;
                    delay_interval = Constants.DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL;
                }
                startServiceTimer();
            }

            return START_STICKY;



        }
        return startId;
    }

    private void StartActivity(android.content.Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Intent Intent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {


    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            // public void run() {
            // @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {

                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("callMade", "1");
                    editor.commit();



                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats
                            .getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats
                            .getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String tag = ";";
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag,
                            mobileStr, totalStr);

                    // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences
                    SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME,
                                    0);
                    //Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_month", info);
                    editor.commit();

                    // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data
                    // usage) and save the current time
                    String sms = "";
                    sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                    sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, sms
                                + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                null, null);
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                null, null);
                    }





                } else {

                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    if (settings.getString("callsMade", "1").equals(1)) {

                        // SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        // .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        if (settings.getString("status", "0").equals(1)) {

                            // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                            double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats
                                    .getTotalRxBytes()
                                    + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                            double mobileBytes = TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileRxBytes()
                                    + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                            totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                            totalBytes /= 1000000;
                            mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                            String tag = ";";
                            String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                            String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                            String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag,
                                    mobileStr, totalStr);

                            // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences
                            SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                                    .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME,
                                            0);
                            Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                            editor.putString("last_month", info);
                            editor.commit();

                            // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data
                            // usage) and save the current time
                            String sms = "";
                            sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                            sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                                    + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                                            .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                                            .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                                String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                        Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                        Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                                smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, sms
                                        + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                        null, null);
                                editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                        System.currentTimeMillis());
                                editor.commit();
                            } else {
                                SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                        Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                        sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                        null, null);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, delay_interval, period);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: is it just not repeating or not starting at all? how do you start the Service?

Comment: It starts - it just never reaches private void startServiceTimer() {

Comment: Does it get inside 
    else if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                    "//USR;0"))?

Comment: @user2533377 are you NoobDev954?

Comment: Don't use a timer. Create an alarm using AlarmManager.

Comment: @E.Odebugg Who? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Not an option - the spec sheet requires a timer.

Comment: @user2533377 this is the same question as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224634/service-should-repeat-every-15-seconds-but-does-not?rq=1

Comment: I work at a large cell provider - there are several of us working on the same project - I know Amani - he is my coworker. It appears he had the same issue issue.

Comment: Did you debug it using a break point? what happens when you reach the call to startServiceTimer()?

Comment: It hits it - then does not proceeded to debug the startServiceTimer

Comment: why you have require this thing?

Comment: It is only executing every 15 seconds for testing purposes - the timeframe will be greatly extended in production

Comment: ...any suggestions as to how I can get it up and running again? The source was functioning up until recently - I simply need to know how I can reinable it's current functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IntentService`'s [onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) with a `while(true) {...}` loop that does a `Thread.sleep(...)` in every iteration.

Having said this, I personally wouldn't install an app that polls every 15 seconds all the time. It would kill my battery. Is there no event you could subscribe to?

**Edit**

Sample code based on the first hit I found on Google (http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/):

```
public class SimpleIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final String PARAM_IN_MSG = "imsg";
    public static final String PARAM_OUT_MSG = "omsg";
    public SimpleIntentService() {
    super("SimpleIntentService");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_IN_MSG);

    while(true) {

        // TODO: poll for sms text messages here

        SystemClock.sleep(15000); // 15 seconds
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is only executing every 15 seconds for testing purposes - the timeframe will be greatly extended in production

Comment: ...any suggestions as to how I can get it up and running again? The source was functioning up until recently - I simply need to know how I can reinable it's current functionality.